# Best way to handle time from input

Tags: python, date, time

I'm trying to get a date and a hour from the user.

```
date = raw_input("enter date (example: 25/12/1990) ")
hour = raw_input("enter hour (example: 20:00) ")
```

That is how I have done that, but I think this is not a good way to implement it.
After the input I would like to compare the inputted time to the current time, and to other times.
I have planned to use the `time` module of python.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Your example time isn't very good.  Neither is your date.  I'd suggest samples of 12/25/1990 and 14:25 so that it is clear that it is MM/DD/YYYY, unless of course you intend the opposite.  On the time, this shows that you intend to use a 24 hour clock.  Unless of course, you don't want a 24 hour clock, they'll need to specify AM/PM.

Comment: @jgritty You are right. I have updated these.

Comment: Look at `strptime` to process date and time strings....

Comment: @JonClements Thank you. this is what I'm doing right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above gives you a date as a string. You'll need to convert that string into a [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) object, and handle any errors which arise. If you restrict your users to simple dates then you can do everything with the datetime module, like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date = "15/03/2012"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 15, 0, 0)
>>> hour = "13:01"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(hour, "%H:%M")
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 13, 1)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(date + " " + hour, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 15, 13, 1)

>>> date = "1/4/2012"
>>> hour = "3:01"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(date + " " + hour, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 1, 3, 1)
```

You can use other datetime module code to do things like get the current date and time, or to find difference between two dates or times.

Comment: Thanks, Even though I have to use the date module, I understood the concept of strptime and now I will be able to use it.

Comment: There is no 'date' module, so I assume you mean you have to use the 'time' module. Why? The datetime module is almost certainly the best built-in module for your use case.

Comment: Yes, my bad.
That's because this excercise is to practise working with this module.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solutions I've ever seen — [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package, they have parser module with `parse()` function, trying to extract date/time from strings. Look examples [here](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2).

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use the built-in date module.